# Access another function Session

Tags: php

I would like an access an array multiple Times For that purpose I store the array in Session array with following session declaration

```
$_SESSION['data'] = array();
```

> Is there any Possible to use $_SESSION like common variable
>
> Intially it calls a function index(), and click anoher button it sets
>   formval = 1 and goes to function index2

```
<?php

new SampleController();
session_start();
class SampleController {
    public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['formval']) && $_REQUEST['formval'] == '1') {
            self::index2();
        } else {
            self::index();
        }
    }

    public function getfunc1() {
        $_SESSION['data'] = array();
        $datarray = array('0', '1', '2');
        $_SESSION['data'] = $datarray;
    }

    public function getfunc2() {
        print_r($_SESSION);
        $val = $_SESSION['data'];
    }
}
```

It Shows Like

> Undefined variable: _SESSION

I expect to need to access the `$_SESSION['data']` array

Comment: 2 methods with the same name in that class?

Comment: I am sorry for that is Typical Mistake

Comment: have you started the session?

Comment: thanks for reply, but i defined session_start() under the class already i forget to wrote that line on post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this will work for you.

```
<?php 
session_start();

class SampleController {

    public function getfunc1(){
        $datarray = array('0','1','2');
        $_SESSION['data'] = $datarray;
    }

    public function getfunc2(){
        return $_SESSION['data'];
    }

}

$SampleController = new SampleController();
$SampleController->getfunc1();
$data = $SampleController->getfunc2();
print_r($data);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer Prince - tell them why it is correct (because he was starting the session after trying to read it)

Answer (score 0):

You have add session start before class declaration. If session start is added inside the method then it gives Undefined variable: _SESSION. 
Either you have to add session_start is all the method or you can add session star at the start.
Here is eample

```
class Api
{
    public function getName()
    {
        session_start();
        $data = array('name'=>'Ashoka P');
        $_SESSION['name'] = '1';
        echo json_encode($data);

    }   

    public function getAge()
    {
        echo '123';
    }
}
```

If you try to access getAge method in the above then it give undefined _SESSION error.
Whereas below will not result in the error

```
session_start();
class Api
{
    public function getName()
    {
        $data = array('name'=>'Ashoka P');
        $_SESSION['name'] = '1';
        echo json_encode($data);

    }   

    public function getAge()
    {
        echo '123';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I added the session_start(); but i can't able to access the another function session.In above getAge() function i would like access the session of getName() - $_SESSION['name'] is it any possible for this.

Comment: if you try try access session before it is set you will get error. In your case if try to access $_SESSION['name'] inside getAge() without setting that session it throws an error.

Comment: i first call the session write function and call get session function this order i used

Comment: @Vasirajan can you add result of print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Undefined variable: _SESSION;it seems like this

Comment: Thanks for replying i solved by defining a session_start() before the class call.

Comment: @Vasirajan thats what mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
new SampleController();
session_start();
```

start the session first

```
session_start();
new SampleController();
```